# Removing whitespace above/below images within a grid

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to produce a grid of images, with a fixed column width, for example three columns, with unfixed heights of varying size. I'm using the beaver-builder plugin, using the Posts module which I would like to stick with. The problem is that the images have whitespace beneath/above them, like this:
[image: Current]
Where I would like the images to bunch together like this:
[image: Aim]

I've been messing around with styling, and it seems like each image is within a fixed height box. This is the html for the grid and bounding boxes for each image,the highlighted line is the div containing the image.
[image: HTML]

If you have any ideas, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Please paste some code, not an image of your code which is impossible for us to debug. Read this [section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [column-count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count):

```
#blocks {
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 0px;
}
.block {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid-column;  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px; // can be different heights
}
```

Example:

```css
#blocks {
 column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 0px;
}
.block {
  background:red;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid-column;  
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}
.block:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue;
}
.block:nth-child(1) {
  height:50px;
}
.block:nth-child(2) {
  height:200px;
}
.block:nth-child(3) {
  height:150px;
}
.block:nth-child(4) {
  height:30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="blocks">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```